# how to draw ROC curve in computer vision algorithm?

Tags: curve, roc

I used a detection algorithm to detect the object in 100 images, with each image containing exactly 2 truth, i.e., each image contains 2 objects. then I added noise and find the best one. I calculated the intersection area between detection result and the ground truth intArea, and also the union area unionArea = rectA + rectB - intArea. then I planned to use these ratios to draw ROC curve as follows:

```
init TP, FP as 100X1 array.
for threshold = 0..1, step = 0.01
    curIdx = 1;
    for each ratio(i), i = 1..100
        if ratio(i) > threshold then
           TP(curIdx) = TP(curIdx) + 1;
        else
           FP(curIdx) = FP(curIdx) + 1;
     end
end
```

then I used TP/100 as Y axis value, and TP/(TP+FP) as X axis value to draw ROC curve.
but the result is not as expected: (I can't post image now because I'm a new user -_-)
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-cuNKyobdV7E/UMkiJmrhTFI/AAAAAAAAEQg/B5twqcZtlQA/s560/roc.jpg

So, would anyone plz help me and tell me where I was wrong? thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

[VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/index.html) implements a very easy way to draw ROC curve under the Matlab environment. Please check this link: http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/plots-rank.html

Comment: Thank you~! I've solved that problem, it is mainly because of my misunderstanding of ROC's definition, which is detailed described in the following paper:https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/295592/1/davisgoadrichcamera2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the internals of ROC graph generation, you can read [Tom Fawcett's report on ROC Graphs](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2003/HPL-2003-4.pdf) or his 
[ScienceDirect article](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/workshops/mir2009/references/ROCintro.pdf).

If you just want to generate the plots without going to its technicalities, you can use [Yard phyton library](https://github.com/ntamas/yard) or [ROCR R package](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/)